# Python SQLite3 global database connection

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Can anyone tell me if this will work. When you open a SQLite database connection to your database file in the *main* of your python application and then call that variable as a global connection each time you need to execute to database in a function.

As seen below. Will this even work?

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect(database)

def db_add_records(_number, _data):
   global con
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute(whatever sql you think of)
   con.commit()
```

Instead of each time creating a new connection to the database inside each function, as I have seen some people do.

Cleaner?

Comment: You could just try it out.. Yes, it'll work, and the `global con` is not even needed as you are never *assigning* to `con` in the function.

Comment: add `for i in xrange(1000): db_add_record()` and give it a try.

Comment: Do read the [*Common issues* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#common-issues) if you are going to use threads; better create a connection per thread in that case. You are good otherwise.

Comment: Is this a recommended way of only making one database connection?